# Call a concrete method on an concrete object which current type is an abstract object

Tags: java

I have the following abstract class which ensures that all subclasses contain the method `eval()`.

```
public abstract class ExpressionTreeNode {
        abstract double eval();
}
```

I would like to create **several** concrete classes which inherit from ExpressionTreeNode, like the class `Addition`. Theses concrete classes contain two other concrete classes (`right` and `left`), which inherit from `ExpressionTreeNode`. Since there might be different concrete classes I defined the variable type as `ExpressionTreeNode`.

Furthermore I would like to call the `eval()` method from these concrete classes. But Eclipse says at this point (e.g. `double arg1 = right.eval();`):

> The method eval() is undefined for the type ExpressionTreeNode

Why is it undefined? There can't be a object which is only of the type `ExpressionTreeNode` and therefore it will contain the `eval()` method.

```
public class Addition extends ExpressionTreeNode {

    ExpressionTreeNode left;
    ExpressionTreeNode right;

    public double eval() {
        double arg1 = left.eval();
        double arg2 = right.eval();

        return arg1+arg2;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem (without using an interface instead of the abstract class)?

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The method is not public and your `Addition` class is not in the same package.

Comment: You would have found this error when adding `@Override` - always a sensible thing to do. Especially `public` is not needed for an interface, and when you change it to an interface, `public` must be added. @daniu give your comment as answer.

Comment: @daniu - I'd expect the error message to be more explicit if that were the case (`javac` says `Cannot be accessed from outside package`).  Although maybe Eclipse's compiler behaves differently here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daniu notes in the comments, this is likely due to not making your method public.

Here's a working example that shows your basic architecture is valid:

```
public class TreeClasses {
    public static abstract class ExpressionTreeNode {
        public abstract double eval();
    }

    public static class Addition extends ExpressionTreeNode {

        ExpressionTreeNode left;
        ExpressionTreeNode right;

        public Addition(ExpressionTreeNode left, ExpressionTreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public double eval() {
            double arg1 = left.eval();
            double arg2 = right.eval();

            return arg1+arg2;
        }
    }

    public static class Constant extends ExpressionTreeNode {
        double val;

        public Constant(double val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public double eval() {
            return val;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExpressionTreeNode tree = new Addition(new Constant(1),new Constant(2));
        System.out.println(tree.eval());
    }
}
```